# Regarding Binary to Float Conversion in c# program

Tags: c#

```
float resultInteger = 0.0f; 
float power = 1/2.0f;

for (i = highPointPosition+1; i <= highResultIndex; i++, power /= 2           
    resultInteger += result[i] * power;
power = 1.0f;

for (i = highPointPosition, power = 1.0f; i >= 0; i--, power *= 2)
    resultInteger += result[i] * power;

if (carry == 1)
 resultInteger += carry * power;
```

The above code converts binary to floating point number.
I have been given an assignment asking me to convert two floating point numbers to binary and then adding them and then converting the result to float.

In the above code when I perform `3.5 + 5.39` the result should be `8.89`, but instead it is `8.889999`.

For others like `9.5 + 7.39` the answer is right i.e., `16.89`.

Can Anyone help explain why I am encountering such problem?

Comment: Try using `double` or `decimal` data type and see the difference. If you want exact precision in arithmetic operations, use `decimal`.

Comment: I have tried both decimal and double ,I got the same result no matter what.

Comment: Scaling by using `Math.Round` with 2 decimal places should help. You don't need to calculate the rest of floating-point numbers.

Comment: So is result an array of 0 and 1?

Comment: Can you post your full code so we have something to work with. obviously the problem is the precision  of a IEEE floating point value. however we cant reliably test and answer if we cant reproduce the problem

Comment: float or double should never be relied on being  an exact number.    If you want that, use decimal

Comment: The truth is, `Decimal` too is a floating point value, and suffers from the same problem, however it has a much higher precision

Comment: yes the array contains zeroes and ones

Comment: code is 177 lines long ?should I post it ?

Comment: `Decimal` uses base 10 exponents and suffers less from rounding issues during base conversions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It happens for the reason that `1/10` can't be expressed accurately in binary system.

You can try the following:

```
float a = 3.5f;
float b = 5.39f;

Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(a + b, 2));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Use `Math.Round(value, digits)`, you can get the result you want.

Comment: I didn't understand you . I have been given an assignment to convert the float numbers to binary and then add them and finally convert the result into float.

Answer (score 2):

Binary can't expression `1/10` in decimal accurately, like how base 10 can't expression `1/3` accurately, while base 12 can (1 third is `0.4` in base 12).

Normally, if you want to get better math accuracy, you would use `decimal` to do the math instead, like this:

```
decimal x = 2.5M;
decimal y = 1.19M;

Console.WriteLine(x + y);
```

`decimal` works because it calculates in base ten, not binary. However, if your professor is asking you to do convert into binary to do the math, then it doesn't matter what the initial type was. It will never be possible to get the correct result with binary.

Comment: Right, thanks. I never actually used `decimal` so I didn't know it would give an error.